# Facebook Graph API post to page feed - Error (#100)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an app in my website that post the new register inserted on database to my facebook page. So it's dynamic. The app receive data like that:

```
array(
'name' => 'name of register',
'link' => 'url refering to the register in my website',
'image' => 'url refering to register image in my website',
'description' => 'description of register')
```

and post to facebook page feed.

Since I updated my graph version to v2.11, my app stop work. When I try to post, it return the error "(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params".

Looking for solutions, I found that I need have ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts), by adding my host in the business settings. I've done that, generated new access token and when I verify if I have the ownership_permissions, the graph explorer returns 'true':

```
{
  "https://www.vitrinevirtual.me/": {
    "ownership_permissions": {
      "can_customize_link_posts": true
    },
    "id": "https://www.vitrinevirtual.me/"
  }
}
```

but the error (#100) still there.

**EDIT:** when I try with static values for 'name', 'link', 'image' and 'description', it works fine!

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: which API endpoint you called?

Comment: '/{page-id}/feed'

Comment: which link do you use? Please check the protocol.

Comment: link to my website? It's something like https://www.vitrinevirtual.me/product-1 and https://www.vitrinevirtual.me/uploads/img-name.jpg

Comment: I mean the error above that only owners of a domain may modify the link information, than you added your domain as you described above. So I try to sort out problems with a wrong domain name. Wrong protocol (http instead of https), missing www or different subdomain.

Comment: humm... I understand now, make sense, but that's correct... like in my edit, when I try with static values, I mean, with the links I already have inserted in my website, it works fine...

Comment: I do not understand which parameters to send to "/<page-id>/feed" to check the ownership_permissions of the link.
Is it a POST request? What are the parameters?